# Laravel - check if the Eloquent object is found inside model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my controller I would like to have this:

```
class TodoController extends Controller {

    public function getDone($todoId)
    {
        Todo::find($todoId)->markAsDone();
    }

}
```

model I have:

```
class Todo extends Eloquent {

    public function markAsDone()
    {
        if (???) {
            $this->is_done = 1;
            $this->save();
        }
    }

}
```

How can I check if the model is found and is present in `$this`?

Comment: So, this can't be done since NULL is returned when nothing found via `::find()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, checking the existence of `ToDo` object can only be done in controller. Because in your current code `Todo::find($todoId)->markAsDone();` if the `$todoId` is invalid, you will be have BIG error, `trying to get property of non-object`. So its better to do this.

```
class TodoController extends Controller {

public function getDone($todoId)
{
    $todo = Todo::find($todoId);
    if ($todo) {
       $todo->markAsDone();
    }
}

}
```

And in your model

```
class Todo extends Eloquent {

    public function markAsDone()
    {
         $this->is_done = 1;
         $this->save();
    }

}
```